# Is there a tool that can generate call to rest web service

Tags: json, web-services, wcf, rest, wcf-endpoint

I have a URL to rest web service (made in WCF with JSON endpoint) that I call by passing `JSON` with all parameters.
But I don't know some parameters names.
Is there some tool where I can enter service URL and method name to get `JSON` example that I must pass to this method?
I know that tools like this exist for `SOAP` services but I need for `REST`.

I just tried to use wcf test client but I can't load the JSON endpoint it's only for SOAP.

```
...svc/json
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Mozilla firefox addon "rest client"]
There are various addons for rest and soap services. you can try as per your requirement.

Comment: With this plugin I can't see exposed methods on json endpoint.